# How do I insert read-only, HTTP-style headers with editable values?

Tags: text-properties

I'm creating a 'form' of sorts in a buffer that has a few required arguments:

```
Title:
Labels:

content content content
```

When the form is presented, I'd like to be able to edit any and all text after each `Header:` without being able to move point *into* `Header:` -- kindof like a minibuffer prompt.

After looking at the definition of `read-from-minibuffer` for the right properties, here's what I've got so far:

```
(defun my--insert-header (header &optional default-value)
  ;; inhibit point from moving inside the field
  (setq-local inhibit-point-motion-hooks nil)
  ;; insert Header: Default-Value pairs
  (let ((props1 '(front-sticky t rear-non-sticky t field t read-only t intangible t face magit-header-line))
        (props2 '(front-sticky nil rear-non-sticky nil field nil read-only nil intangible nil)))
    (insert (apply #'propertize (format "%s: " header) props1))
    (insert (apply #'propertize (or value "") props2))
    (insert (apply #'propertize "\n" props1))))
```

When I run this code in a scratch buffer

```
(progn
  (insert "\n\n\n")
  (my--insert-header "Title" "some title"))
```

I get an error.  I think it's because `(insert (apply #'propertize (or value "") props2))` is trying to insert at read-only text, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing that without compromising the desired behavior.

Comment: You have `rear-non-sticky` in your code, but it should be `rear-nonsticky`.

Comment: Show the error you get. You can bind `inhibit-read-only` around your `insert`s.